# Auto Forward mails to Gmail from iCloud Mail or iCloud Mail on Android

Tags: email, gmail, android, apple-mail, icloud

I want to do auto forward receiving mails from Mail to Gmail. Also it can be asked like this: How can I see my iCloud mails on my android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMail cannot access a third party mail provider unless the third party provides that mail using POP3. [Apple's iCloud does not support POP](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864). I don't use an Android phone, but I suspect the best way to view your iCloud mail on your Android phone is to use a third party mail client, like [K-9 Mail](http://lifehacker.com/5812657/the-best-email-client-for-android).

You can configure that mail client to pull down both your GMail mail and your iCloud mail.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Forwarding iCloud email to Gmail

To automatically forward your iCloud email to a Gmail account:

Open up [iCloud Mail](https://www.icloud.com/#mail) in a browser, click the gear in the top-right corner, and select **Preferences...**

[image: Gear Menu]

On the **General** tab, in the **Forwarding** section, check the box to **Forward my email to:** and enter your email address.

[image: General Preferences]

Click **Done** to save your changes.

---

### 2. Checking iCloud email on Android

The **Email** app in Android (this is different from the **Gmail** app) supports IMAP email accounts. Open up the **Email** app and if you have never used it, you should be asked to enter your email address and password. Enter your @me.com address (**not** your @icloud.com address) and password. The app should configure everything automatically.